# DAO not reading all recordsets properly

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, report

I have two functions which create record sets for me which i then read into a spreadsheet.

However this one excel report has columns which start with no data, and for some strange reason for the first time ever it doesn't read the entire column's data from the file.

For example, some types of lines have column a, b, c with values, some have in d,e,f and some in g,h,i. So for example it so happens that a,b,c is first to have values, but d through i are blanks for several record lines. It seems because of that the ENTIRE column ranges of d to i are blank after the record set is placed in the sheet.

Why?

This is the code that places the data in the spreadsheets:

```
Public Sub PutRecordsetInSheet(ByVal RS As Object, ByVal TopLeft As Range, _
Optional ByVal Headers As Boolean = True)
'Lists field names in the top row if Headers=True
'Pastes the records below them.

    Dim i As Integer
    If Headers Then
        For Each objField In RS.Fields
            i = i + 1
            TopLeft.Cells(1, i).Value = objField.Name
        Next objField
        TopLeft.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset RS
    Else
        TopLeft.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset RS
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code I use to load files and I have the parameters in a spreadsheet based on what the excel file format is:

```
Public Sub OpenFiles(SettingsSheet As Worksheet, FileCnt As Integer, _
    ByRef FileToOpen() As String, ByRef FileSettings() As String, _
    ByRef Connection() As Object, RecordSets() As Object, ByRef SheetsArr() As Variant)

    'Set File Count
    ReDim FileToOpen(1 To 3, 1 To FileCnt) As String
    Dim SFile As Integer

    'Prepare Dialogs
    For cnt = 1 To FileCnt
        FileToOpen(1, cnt) = SettingsSheet.Cells(cnt + 1, "B") 'Dialog Report File Description
        FileToOpen(2, cnt) = SettingsSheet.Cells(cnt + 1, "C") 'Dialog File Extension Choices"
    Next cnt

    'Prompt File Dialogs
    For cnt = 1 To FileCnt
        Dim fDialog As FileDialog, result As Integer
        Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'File Dialog Properties
        With fDialog
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Title = FileToOpen(1, cnt)
            .InitialFileName = WorkingPath
            'File filters
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "Report Files", FileToOpen(2, cnt)
            'Show the dialog. -1 means success!
            .Show
            If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                FileToOpen(3, cnt) = .SelectedItems(1)
            ElseIf .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Or .SelectedItems.Count = Empty Then
                SFile = cnt
                GoTo Cancelled:
            End If
        End With
    Next

    'Prepare Connection Settings
    Dim CSet As String
    ReDim FileSettings(1 To 3, 1 To FileCnt)

    For cnt = 1 To FileCnt
        CSet = LCase(Right(FileToOpen(3, cnt), Len(FileToOpen(3, cnt)) - InStrRev(FileToOpen(3, cnt), ".")))

        x = Application.Match(CSet, SettingsSheet.Range("E1:E" & SettingsSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row), 0)
        If Not (IsError(x)) Then
                FileSettings(1, cnt) = SettingsSheet.Cells(x, "F") 'Provider
                FileSettings(2, cnt) = SettingsSheet.Cells(x, "G") 'Extended Properties 1
                FileSettings(3, cnt) = SettingsSheet.Cells(x, "H") 'Extended Properties 2
        End If
        Set x = Nothing
    Next cnt

    'Establish Connections and prepare Record Sets
    ReDim Connection(1 To FileCnt)
    ReDim RecordSets(1 To FileCnt)

    For cnt = 1 To FileCnt
        Set Connection(cnt) = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set RecordSets(cnt) = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        With Connection(cnt)
        .Provider = FileSettings(1, cnt)
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FileToOpen(3, cnt) & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=" & Chr(34) & FileSettings(2, cnt) & ";" & _
        FileSettings(3, cnt) & Chr(34) & ";"
        .Open
        End With
    Next cnt

    Exit Sub
Cancelled:
        MsgBox "No " & FileToOpen(1, SFile) & " File Specified.", vbExclamation, "User Cancelled"

        On Error Resume Next
        Call DelTmpSheets(SheetsArr())
        FinalReport.Delete
        Err.Clear
        AppDefaults
        End
End Sub
```

Comment: It's impossible to replicate your results with the info you have provided.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the data that's like that?

Comment: Please show us the Access queries as certain calculated expressions could interfere.

Comment: It's in Excel and it's an Excel file that I am loading, so within this excel file there are far right columns that on the first few record lines / rows are blank and those ones end up entirely blank columns even though many rows down there are values, then again it skips and there aren't.

Comment: This is the code I use: